# Flutter custom stepper

Tags: flutter, dart, stepper, dart-ui

Need help with creating a stepper that increase fractionally like each main step have 3 question and at each question stepper increase by 0.30. after 3rd question one main step is completed.

Please see attached image for clarity.[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX27C.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal Stepper in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484581/horizontal-stepper-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Search on Google(horizontal-stepper-in-flutter). A lot of recourse is available about this topic.

Please research a little bit before asking a question. Check more solutions and same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484581/horizontal-stepper-in-flutter)

Comment: I know how to use horizontal stepper.but I want to increase stepper fractionally between two step.please read my requirement clearly.